# Можно ли в 1C изменить тему?

Tags: 1с, design

Можно ли как-то в 1C добавить свою тему, а не выбрать из 2 существующих в конфигураторе?

Comment: Вы какие темы имеете ввиду конкретно? Редактора в конфигураторе? Или же самого предприятия?

Comment: @Sublihim, в самом предприятии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С версии 8.3.13 введена поддержка корпоративных стилей.
Это можно реализовать с использованием объекта конфигурации **Стиль**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В управляемом приложении доступна настройка только пяти стилевых цветов, которые используются в интерфейсе **Такси**

- **Цвет навигации** устанавливает цвет фона панели разделов;
- **Цвет дополнительной навигации** устанавливает цвет фона панели функций
  текущего раздела;
- **Цвет активности** применяется к следующим элементам интерфейса:

  - рамка текущего элемента формы,
  - фон текущего элемента меню,
  - фон текущей строки и ячейки таблицы;
- **Цвет важного** устанавливает цвет фона кнопки по умолчанию;
- **Цвет акцентирования** применяется к следующим элементам интерфейса:

  - текст заголовка группы,
  - отметка флажка,
  - переключателя и полосы регулирования,
  - индикатор текущей формы в панели открытых.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]